# Django rest framework doesn't commit data to sqlite3 via POST untill server restarted

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[CLOSED]I just started to study django rest framework and encountered with problem.
Here is my code (views.py, urls.py, models.py, serializers.py):

```
#view.py:
class AllData(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Run.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RunSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
        end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
        if start_date is not None and end_date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(Q(date__gte=start_date) & Q(date__lte=end_date))
        return queryset


#serializers.py:
class RunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Run
        fields = '__all__'


#models.py:
class Run(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
    time = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.distance)


#urls.py:
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('all_runs', AllData, basename='all_runs')

urlpatterns = [
    path('average_data/', AverageData.as_view(), name='average_data'),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

So, i started with http://127.0.0.1:8000/all_runs/ and it works.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/all_runs/1 or something else - too.
(i have added some data already).
I see POST, DELETE options, etc. in drf web interface.
But...if i add data via POST:

1. i see  "POST /all_runs/ HTTP/1.1" 201 9187 - seems like OK.
2. try to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/all_runs/ again... and don't see added data!
3. restart server (django by default, sqlite3, etc.) and... see added data!
   Seems like POST works, but i see data after re-starting server only in web-interface of drf. Same problems with Postman.
   Please, help. What is wrong in my code or common settings of django or something else?
   Thank you in advance!

p.s. there is an additional url to "average". i've skipped such view - it's out of my question.

UPD: have got advice and removed .all() from queryset in class and put it to return. was: queryset = Run.objects.all() + return queryset is: queryset = Run.objects + return queryser.all()
And it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing: `queryset = self.queryset` with `queryset = super().get_queryset()`. It will force re-evaluation of queryset.